# A "reversed" Jensen inequality

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $S= \langle v_0, \ldots, v_n \rangle$   be a non-degenerate simplex in some affine space,
Consider $(x_i)_{i\in I}$  a (finite) family of points in $S$ and $\lambda_i\ge 0$, $\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i =1$ a family of weights.  Write $\sum_{i\in I} \lambda_i x_i = \sum_{k=0}^n \mu_k v_k$ ( $\mu_0$, $\ldots$, $\mu_n$ uniquely determined).

Conclusion:  for every $f\colon S \to \mathbb{R}$ a convex function we have

$$\sum_{i\in I} \lambda_i f(x_i) \le \sum_{k=0}^n \mu_k f(v_k)$$

Notes:

1. A bit surprising to me, and also interesting. I have found  a  variant of it in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0411099) by Andreas Maurer,  indicated to me by @FinleyMarsh.
2. By Jensen's inequality  we have $f(\sum \mu_i x_i) \le \sum \lambda_i f(x_i)$, What is new is  an upper estimate for the RHS. Perhaps a stretch to call it a reversed Jensen, suggestions are welcome

The proof is not  difficult, so I will leave it as a [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).
If  somebody could provide another reference, that would be great.
I will post a solution later on.

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: What are the elements  $v_k$ ? The vertices of the simplex ?

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc: failed to add that, corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The proof is straightforward. Every element $x_i$ admits a unique representation $$x_i=\sum_{k=0}^n\mu_{ik}v_k$$ where $\mu_{ik}\ge 0$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n\mu_{ik}=1.$ We have $$\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_ix_i=\sum_{k=0}^n\mu_kv_k.$$ Hence $\mu_k=\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i\mu_{ik}.$ Therefore by the convexity of $f$ we get $$\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_if(x_i)\le \sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i\sum_{k=0}^n\mu_{ik}f(v_k)\\ =
\sum_{k=0}^nf(v_k)\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i\mu_{ik}=\sum_{k=0}^n\mu_kf(v_k)$$

Comment: Very nice!  Makes it clear why we need $v_k$'s affinely independent.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\ell$ be an affine function (uniquely determined) such that
$$\ell(v_k) = f(v_k)$$ for all $0\le k\le n$.

For every $x\in S$ we have $f(x) \le \ell(x)$ ( by Jensen). Therefore

$$\sum_{i\in I} \lambda_i f(x_i) \le \sum_i\lambda_i \ell(x_i) = \ell( \sum_i \lambda_i x_i) = \ell ( \sum_k \mu_k v_k) = \sum \mu_k \ell( v_k) = \sum_k \mu_k f(v_k)$$

The proof follows the intuition:  the graph of the function is below some hyperplane through the vertices of a simplex.